# why {}__proto__ instanceof !== Object

Tags: javascript

This just does not make sense to me, please someone, explain the last line of it:

```
var o = {};
o.__proto__.isPrototypeOf(Object)  // true
o.__proto__.constructor.name       // 'Object'
o.__proto__.toString()             // '[object Object]'
o.__proto__ instanceof Object      // false (wtf???)
```

Let me rephrase my original question - I am not looking for understanding HOW IT WORKS INTERNALLY BUT **WHY IT WORKS THIS WAY** (although sometimes it helps) - I mean : why JS engine constructs dunder proto (`__proto__`) AS an object which is not instance of Object EVEN if it has 'constructor' set AND even if ALL object literals ARE instances of Object (eg. `o instanceof Object === true`, `({}) instanceof Object === true`).

In other words - instanceof of **WHAT** is dunder proto when dunder proto is not manually constructed ?

And why it has 'constructor' property set if "it's not an instance" as somebody wrote?  According to MDN : "All objects inherit a constructor property from their prototype" - if dunder proto object has constructor property it should mean it was inherited from 'some' prototype... So, it would make sense to me if 'constructor' property was NOT SET for 'root' dunder proto

(I did not use dunder proto as it was discouraged but yesterday I read it's official part of ES6 so I took a look at it)

Comment: Because it's not an instance. Compare with your first line.

Comment: it is an object constructed with 'Object' constructor so how come 'it is not an instance'? (take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Answer (score 3):

`instanceof` does a bit of book-keeping, and then executes the `HasInstance` "method".

`HasInstance` is defined as:

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the argument is likely an Object that was constructed by this object.

Since your object's prototype *wasn't* constructed, it must always return false when using `instanceof`. In contrast,

```
o instanceof Object
```

returns true, because `o` *is* an instance.

How does this actually work? Well, `HasInstance` goes through the whole `prototype` chain of the object it is inspecting. But `o.__proto__` *doesn't have a prototype* - so it's not considered an object, and `HasInstance` returns false.

If you're used to dealing with class-based OOP languages, Javascript's OOP(/FP :P) can be quite a challenge. I'd refer you to some article that explains this well, but sadly, I haven't found any so far - and reading the specification is likely to make you even more confused (it's not one of the better specifications out there).